# SQL compilation error: Format argument for function 'TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ' needs to be a string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am querying data from a internally stage file in snowflake as below -
I get the following error:
SQL compilation error: Format argument for function 'TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ' needs to be a string

Any idea what could be going wrong here?
Thanks

```
SELECT 
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$10),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$45),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$1,20),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$18,20),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$8),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$42),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$19,20),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$11),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$16),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$49),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$47::STRING,'21'),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$50::STRING,10),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$48),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$36,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$27,19,6),TO_VARCHAR(stg.$12),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$13::STRING,10),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$5::STRING,10),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$22,20),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$21,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$20,19,6),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$2::STRING,10),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$39,19,6),TO_VARCHAR(stg.$35),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$4),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$40,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$32,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$33,19,6),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$34),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$37),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$38),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$17),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$23),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$14,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$28,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$29,19,6),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$41,6,2),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$31),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$30,19,6),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$24),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$25),
      TO_NUMBER(stg.$26,19,6),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$9),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$3::STRING,10),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$15),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$44),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$43),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$53),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$51::STRING,10),
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$50::STRING,10),
      TO_VARCHAR(stg.$52), 
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$7::STRING,10), 
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$6::STRING,10),                                                              
      'T_RPDB_POLICY_1_0_0',
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::STRING)
      FROM '@INTERNAL_POLICY_STAGE/T_RPDB_POLICY.CSV.gz' (file_format => '"JVCO"."STAGING".CSV') stg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select to_timestamp_tz(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::string)
```

Second argument is format(varchar type) and you are passing number.

```
select to_timestamp_tz('04/05/2013 01:02:03', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html

Comment: and even where you have set the 2nd parameter to be a string, it's not a valid format: TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(stg.$47::STRING,'21') - '21' is not a valid format